# Linux NFS client has unlimited access to shared files from Solaris server

Tags: linux, solaris, file-permissions

I am sharing files with NFS from a Solaris 2.6 server to a Linux Red Hat EL 4 client and also to other solaris 2.6 clients.  On the solaris clients, write access is correctly controlled by file permissions.  On the the Linux client, any user can edit or delete any file, regardless of the file permissions!  Can anyone help me fix the system so that unauthorized users on the RH box can't edit files?

Some extra info:

- Folder is shared as rw with NFS
- Shared folder has drwxrwxrwx permissions.

For example:

```
frank@linux$ ls -l test.txt
-rw-r--r-- joe engineer test.txt 
frank@linux$ rm test.txt 
are you sure you want to remove write protected file (y/n): y
```

the file text.txt is deleted by user frank who does not have write priveledges to this file.

Comment: For example: frank@linux$ ls -l test.txt\n -rw-r--r-- joe engineer test.txt \nfrank@linux$ rm test.txt are you sure you want to remove write protected file (y/n): y \nthe file text.txt is deleted by user frank who does not have write priveledges to this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the folder is 777, this is expected behavior on Linux.

Try 1777 (i.e., turn on the sticky bit) on the directory and only the file owner will be able to modify it.

Comment: Just saw this comment now, I will try this out tomorrow.

Comment: Hmmm, I had assumed that to to delete a file you needed write permission to the directory AND write permission to the file.  Are you saying that is an OR function?

Comment: Yes, it's effectively an 'or' without the sticky bit. See  http://www.linuxfocus.org/English/January1999/article77.html and scroll down to the "T-bit, SUID and SGID" section.

Comment: Ok, I see now that I did not understand the meaning of file permissions correctly.  Thanks for answering my noob question.

Comment: Hey, outside of ugo/rwx, all of the remaining permission bits are weird. Not really a noob question, more an obscure corner of the OS.